# Java interface not working on URL opening

Tags: java, url, browser

I'm creating an application in which a button needs to open the browser to a target webpage.

I've tried many solutions to this but none of these worked for me.

The following code snippet is tied to a OnAuction button.

```js
    public static void openWebpage() throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code);
    }
```

This is the only snippet that does not freeze the program when attempting to connect to website.

It is my latest try, the response code is 200, which would mean a successful attempt to connect to website. However, the webpage does not open.

There are no compilation nor execution errors.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: *However, the webpage does not open.* There's nothing in that code *opening* a web page. See `java.awt.Desktop` for opening web pages

Comment: I know, I tried to use Desktop but it freezes the program

Comment: You should run it in a separate thread. Look at the well-documented Javadoc for `SwingWorker`